# Check if key value exist and if not push key with value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Suppose I have response array from my web-service like this

```
Array1 = [
      0:[{name:A,count:2,hours:3},{name:B,count:3,hours:3},{name:C,count:2,hours:4}]
      1:[{name:A,count:3,hours:4},{name:B,count:3,hours:3},{name:C,count:2,hours:2}]
      2:[{name:A,count:3,hours:1},{name:B,count:3,hours:4},{name:C,count:2,hours:5},{name:D,count:2,hours:3}]
    ];
```

and

```
Array2 = ['A','B','C','D'];
```

In my output, I need to check for 24 hours.But for simplicity,we will now take only hours to 5.Each sub array from Array1 belong to one user. Now,I must group array by hours and activity. Means I need to make key as name and value as total count of name in each hours.

And output must look like this

```
var output = [
               {hours:1, A:3, B:0, C:0, D:0},
               {hours:2, A:0, B:0, C:2, D:0},
               {hours:3, A:2, B:6, C:0, D:2},
               {hours:4, A:3, B:3, C:2, D:0},
               {hours:5, A:0, B:0, C:2, D:0},
             ];
```

And my try below

```
angular.forEach(Array1 , function(array){ //angularjs foreach
    array.forEach(function(a){
      obj[a.hours] = obj[a.hours]||[0];
      if(obj[a.hours].hasOwnProperty(a.name)){
        obj[a.hours][a.name] = parseInt(obj[a.hours][a.name]) + parseInt(a.count);
      }else{
        obj[a.hours][a.name] = parseInt(a.count);
      }
      obj[a.hours]['hours'] = a.hours;
    });
  });
```

where I try to group my array with hours and name as key and total count as value. What more I try is

```
 var startHour = 1;
 var endHours = 5;
 var newData = [];  //@TODO
 newData.push(obj); //@TODO
 for(i= startDate; i < endDate; i++) {
    var found = newData.some(function(el){
      //el.forEach(function(a){
        $.each(el, function(key, value) {
          if(value.hours){
            return value.hours === i;
          }
      });
    });
    if(!found){
      console.log(i + "not found");
      newData.push([{'hours':i}]);
    }
  }
  console.log(newData);
```

But every time I am in not found.As my output I need to push key-value pairs name and count 0 if not exit. But first I try to push only hours if not exists. Can anyone suggest me what I did wrong. I am back-end programmer so,I don't have good knowledge of JavaScript.

Thank You.

Comment: Array1 is an Object, not an array

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. I try to copy it from my console.

Comment: return returns to the jquery routine... and looping trough all elements in a function that loops trough all elements (some) doesnt make that much sense

Comment: I know second part of my coding is not good code. Even I put my obj object to newData array is also without sense. Is part of code that I try to get my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the reference of the right hour object and iterate the data with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Later sort the result array for the wanted order.

```js
var array1 = [[{ name: 'A', count: 2, hours: 3 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 3 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 4 }], [{ name: 'A', count: 3, hours: 4 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 3 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 2 }], [{ name: 'A', count: 3, hours: 1 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 4 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 5 }, { name: 'D', count: 2, hours: 3 }]],
    array2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    grouped = [];

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        if (!this[b.hours]) {
            this[b.hours] = { hours: b.hours };
            array2.forEach(function (c) { this[c] = 0; }, this[b.hours]);
            grouped.push(this[b.hours]);
        }
        this[b.hours][b.name] += b.count;
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

grouped.sort(function (a, b) { return a.hours - b.hours; });

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Proposal with 24h array, with zero based `hour`.

```js
var array1 = [[{ name: 'A', count: 2, hours: 3 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 3 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 4 }], [{ name: 'A', count: 3, hours: 4 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 3 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 2 }], [{ name: 'A', count: 3, hours: 1 }, { name: 'B', count: 3, hours: 4 }, { name: 'C', count: 2, hours: 5 }, { name: 'D', count: 2, hours: 3 }]],
    array2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    grouped = Array.apply(null, { length: 24 }).map(function (_, i) {
        var o = { hours: i }
        array2.forEach(function (a) { this[a] = 0; }, o);
        return o;
    });

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        grouped[b.hours][b.name] += b.count;
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Scholz for response.And I get my output as mentions in question But my problem is I need to loop through 24 hours.What if some hours are not in my response array?

Comment: is it always 24 hours? is it starting with zero?

Comment: ya, I need to do for 24 hours and some hours cannot be in my Array1 also.

Comment: @Scholz just a small question. In your Array.apply how you did i++? I ask you because I need to do same with day interval also.Which part of code is doing increment?This is just my question.

Comment: it is the `i` in the callback `function (_, i) { /* ... */}`. the API of `Array#forEach` does incrementing.

Comment: @Scholz can you suggest me for date interval.suppose, startDate = 2016-11-10 and endDate = 2016-11-20.How can I loop through date?

Comment: maybe you ask another question with this issue. then you could illustrate, what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could start on a array of object (1 object per hour). And pushing inside this array the new additional count coresponding the hour and name :

```js
var Array1 = [[{name: "A",count: 2,hours: 3},{name: "B",count: 3,hours: 3},{name: "C",count: 2,hours: 4}],[{name: "A",count: 3,hours: 4},{name: "B",count: 3,hours: 3},{name: "C",count: 2,hours: 2}],[{name: "A",count: 3,hours: 1},{name: "B",count: 3,hours: 4},{name: "C",count: 2,hours: 5},{name: "D",count: 2,hours: 3}]];
var Array2 = ['A','B','C','D'];
var res = [1,2,3,4,5].map(x => ({"hours": x})).map(x => {
  Array2.forEach(y => x[y] = 0);
  return x;
});
Array1.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)).forEach(x => {
  if (Array2.indexOf(x.name) !== -1)
    res[x.hours - 1][x.name] += x.count;
})
console.log(res);
```